# How to disable Racket's any s-expression value output

Tags: racket

Example, I write a Racket script:

```
; filename: hello.rkt
#lang racket/base
(displayln "hello")
(+ 1 1)
```

and execute it:

```
$ racket hello.rkt
```

output is:

```
hello
2
```

I don't want it to print the number '2', how to disable result of the any S-expression value output?

Comment: Would it help to [assign the value](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/set_.html) to a variable?

Comment: What is the purpose of such code? Why can't you just comment it out as  ;(+ 1 1)  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `void` to discard values, and `begin` to group several expressions together.  E.g.

```
(void (begin (+ 1 1) (+ 2 2) (+ 3 3)))
```

This prints nothing.

Comment: Is no more elegant way？

Comment: Perhaps you'd prefer `(begin (+ 1 1) (+ 2 2) (void))` ? Or, as @summea mentions, you can bind expression results to names, using `define`.